# What happens to content between ng-view tags ? How can I do a "double-page"?

Tags: django, angularjs

I have to do a website with a double index, for example, if you're not logged in, you see the index page as the website frontpage. But once you're logged in, it stays the same page (at least, same url), but now you're on your personnal account board. Can I do it by putting my website frontpage between

`<div ng-view></div>`

tags ? Will the content be hidden when the url will be reloaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain what you need to do by means of an example. Let us say your base URL is `www.foo.com`

Now, if the user is not logged in, you need to load the route `/bar`, that is, the full URL that you need to load is `www.foo.com/bar`. If the user is logged in, then direct the user to the /boo path, that is, your URL become `www.foo.com/boo`.

**Summarizing**:

Registered users see: `www.foo.com/boo`
Non Registered users see: `www.foo.com/bar`

**Client Side**
Using AngularJS `$routeProvider`, display the appropriate template when the path is `/bar` - a template for non registered users and display a template for path `/boo` - for registered users.

**Server Side**
On your server, when the client makes a request for the templates which should only be displayed to a registered user, verify that the user has logged in before providing the same. For the template to be displayed for non-registered users, you need not need any such checks.

In case the client has not logged in, then redirect the user to either the login page or display the template that needs to be shown to the non-registered user.

All of the above can be achieved using templates and thus using `<div ng-view></div>`